# Paired devices is getting null in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bluetooth

I am developing android blue tooth project .I refered this  link [bluetooth tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_bluetooth.htm) .In which i tried to get the paired device list it shows me null or empty .I tried in SG code device os version is icecream sandwich .Paired device is empty.How can i get the size.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Button list;
private BluetoothAdapter BA;
private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;
private ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

}

```
public void list(View view){
    pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
        list.add(bt.getName());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Showing Paired Devices",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In manifiest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [BlueToothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBondedDevices()). getBondedDevices() can return Null on error also check status of blue tooth. (ON/OFF).

Comment: Thanks Ragu ..Added the Braodcast reciver now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the bluetooth permissions in the manifest file?

Edit: I'm an idiot, here's the android permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```